# Can't find a plugin/connector for SVN/Subversion 1.5 in Eclipse 4.2 (Juno)

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin, subversive

For compatibility with my colleagues, I need to use SVN 1.5 in my install of Eclipse 4.2 Juno, but can't find a compatible plugin which uses an old version of SVN.

I guess I only need the connector, but if I have to use a different plugin then I will.

Am I looking in the wrong places?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/). According to their [download page](http://subclipse.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectProcess?pageID=p4wYuA), the 1.4 release works with Subversion 1.5. Although being old, Subclipse 1.4 can still be downloaded from their mirrors. I have not tried it in Juno, but there's a good chance it will work

*Edit: I assume you ask for a Subversion Client Plugin in Juno*

Answer (score 1):

Subclipse plugin for Eclipse Juno to connect with svn 1.5 server :
You may check once again on the tigris website for the version to download but as far as I remember and what I did use for svn1.5 as a repo download url is http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.4.x in the Eclipse Menu (help/install new software/available software sites). Make sure to remove previously url related to this download operation in case you entered some previously.

Answer (score 0):

why do you wanna use a old version to juno the last

try this page 
http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.5.html